# I tried ng add @angular/pwa, but it failed with this error code that I cannot understand. Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"14.2.0" from @angular/forms@14.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^14.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (@angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @angular/common@"^14.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@14.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"14.2.3" from @angular/common@14.2.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     @angular/common@"^14.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: You have the solution at the end of the message : fix the dependency tree or use --force.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found the answer through angular communities, you just need to run this command on the terminal

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```